# c# devexpress datagrid add row convert type error

Tags: c#, datagridview, devexpress

I have error when I want to add new row in my codes; there is a type error voint to int .

problem line:   clmm=gridView1.AddNewRow();

here my codes;

```
namespace sensor_measure
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int clmm= 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            DateTime new= DateTime.Now;


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
            serialPort1.Open();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            timem= (timem+ 1);
            come = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            this.chartControl1.Series["Veri"].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(timem, come));

          clmm=gridView1.AddNewRow();
```

Comment: Did you try `gridView1.Rows.Add()`? I am not aware of a method called `AddNewRow`

Comment: this is not valid for devexpress

Comment: seems to me that a simple Google search on `GridView.AddNewRow()`  method would be a great place to start, not to mention DevExpress has tons of online working examples

Answer (score 1):

The [GridView.AddNewRow Method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_AddNewRowtopic) is declared as

```
public override void AddNewRow()
```

and has a `void` return type.